# R: Execute a function/script as part of package installation

Tags: r, installation

I am developing an R package that requires a few env setups up in order to function properly. Such as installing additional software (e.g., from `apt-get` or `brew`), make OS configurations (e.g., add directories to `PATH`), and download some test files.

All the necessary configurations are written as an R function (e.g., `setupEnv`), and I am interested in automatically calling this function after `install.packages("myPackage")` is executed.

While it is a viable approach to ask a user to call the setup function, `setupEnv`, after they install my package; however, mainly for UX reasons, I am mostly interested in calling the `setupEnv` method automatically right after the package installation is completed.

Any suggestions on how I can achieve this?

Comment: (1) Don't. Doing something *that "invasive"* is, in my opinion, beyond a reasonable expectation of R packages. Also, often the user running `install.packages` does not have permissions to do that. (2) I don't think you can do any of that with `install.packages`. ...

Comment: (3) The best way to go in my opinion is to look for the presence of the requisite external components in the [`.onLoad`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/ns-hooks.html) package function, and if not present, then `packageStartupMessage("please run myPackage::setupEnv()")`, perhaps with some more descriptive text as to *why* that is necessary. Other packages do that and occasionally have a web page with much more information (per-OS instructions for manual installation, as needed). (Please never auto-install other apps.)

Comment: (4) If it's a linked-library (dll) thing, then I think that dependency should be handled in the `DESCRIPTION` file, likely in a `LinkingTo:` line.

Comment: Good comments, thank you @r2evans